# Simplifying using Big Theta expression

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm learning algorithms and currently trying to understand the big-O notation. One of the exercises question looks like **log(n) + 10^6n^5000 + 3^n**. The task is to simplify the expression using Θ-expression. As I understand it asks to say the Θ for this expression which means it looks like this: **log(n) + 10^6n^5000 + 3^n = Θ(n^5000)**?

Comment: Hope this explanation may help: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But, the result is wrong! It should be `\Theta(3^n)`, as `3^n` is an exponential function and grows faster than a polynomial function such as `n^{5000}`. Also, you can think about the limit of the given function over `3^n` when `n` goes to infinity.